# Current flow through galvanometer in balanced wheatstone bridge

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

In a balanced Wheatstone bridge the potential difference across a galvanometer in the middle is 0 so it is said that current won't flow through it. But if we consider a simple wire with resistance and battery  circuit the potential difference between any two points present between resistance and battery is always 0 (since the wire assumed to be ideal & wire resistance is combined into the above resistance) but a current though flows through it. Is it truly the potential difference which governs the abandoning/absence of galvanometer in a balanced Wheatstone bridge?

Comment: What do you mean by “redundancy”?

Comment: @BobD sir it means no longer in action or abandoned

Answer (score 0):

When you come across claims that wires etc. have "zero resistance", mentally substitute "resistance much smaller than other resistances in the circuit". So a potential difference *is* needed to drive a finite current through a wire, but it is a much smaller one than the potential differences across other resistances in the circuit.

The galvanometer reading is indeed proportional to the potential difference across it. Another example of Ohm's law, but also requiring that the meter reading is proportional to the current through it.

Comment: Sir if I take an ideal wire with no resistance then use ohms law such V=0 & R=0  so 0=i*0 means it doesn't requires any resistance for current to be flown through and pot. diff can be absolute zero.

Comment: " if I take an ideal wire with no resistance [...] That's just what I'm suggesting you DON'T do, if you're looking to understand ordinary circuits. You might be interested, though, to read about *superconductivity*.

Comment: Don't forget that the galvanometer does have resistance and requires a PD across it to drive a current through it. The method of using a Wheatstone bridge requires making the Potential at each side of the galvanometer the same. Only then can you calculate the value of the unknown resistance.